# Contact on substrate of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, cmos, electrical, nmos, pmos

Why do we want to have an ohmic contact on a substrate terminal of mosfet? What would happen if we used schottky contact instead?

Answer (score 1):

FETs are often used as Ideal Diodes when RdsOn is << lower than the load R unlike Schottky diode which have a low threshold but higher Rs than Silicon.  So adding a diode in series would degrade the typical performance for losses as a switch.

We can compare cost, size, power, speed , voltage drop, max current to compare a power Schottky power diode with a power FET. There is no advantage with a Schottky contact.

[Low RdsOn FET](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/taiwan-semiconductor-corporation/TSM018NA03CR-RLG/TSM018NA03CRRLGTR-ND/7360029) 1.8mOhm @ 29A = 52mV , max cont. = 185A (/w heatsink)  < $1 in volume

[High current Schottky FET](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/vishay-semiconductor-diodes-division/V30K45-M3-H/V30K45-M3-HTR-ND/9973051)  630mV @ 30A max cont. current  < $0.50 in volume

- but its "contact" ...
- making it much smaller increases diode series Rs=ΔV/ΔI based on smaller power capacity. Rs[Ω] ~0.5/Pd [W]max for most diodes +/-50%
- whereas RdsOn above is Rs=0.0018Ω and Pd max= 108W +Hsink

[image] is as big as the FET.

Comment: So the implicit assumptions are that the bulk and source are tied together and the on resistance of the shottky diode added to RdsOn will violate the R  << Rload condition?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the polarity of charge movement, the substrate needs to be controlled. A rectifying-contact blocks that control in at least one polarity.

Comment: So it isn't a problem when the substrate is tied to a constant voltage?

Comment: The source-bulk diodes need to be respected. Typically source-substrate re shorted, to get the predictable Vthreshold. Even if the source and drain are implanted directly onto the substrate, the source-substrate tend to be shorted RIGHT AT THE FET, to minimize time-delays in building or in erasing the channel (which impacts time-jitter, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if the bulk and source aren't connected, does it mean that the schottky diode isn't a problem?